# Getting restart count from PM2 node

Tags: pm2

I'm trying to monitor the amount of the restarts, cpu and memory in PM2 module managed microservices and create an alert if the module is restarting using AWS cloud watch.

`pm2 list`

Command returns the data in a UI formatted way which I would like to avoid parsing.

Is there any way to get the number of process restarts in a more machine-readable friendly format than the one returned by the pm2 list command.

I looked at the pm2 get command but can't find documentation about the keys I can use there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all kinds of details (including restarts) in json format with

`pm2 prettylist` (pretty)

or with

`pm2 jlist` (raw).

pm2 also has an api:

```
var pm2 = require('pm2');

// Connect or launch PM2
pm2.connect(function(err) {

  // Start a script on the current folder
  pm2.start('test.js', { name: 'test' }, function(err, proc) {
  if (err) throw new Error('err');

    // Get all processes running
    pm2.list(function(err, process_list) {
      console.log(process_list);

      // Disconnect to PM2
      pm2.disconnect(function() { process.exit(0) });
    });
  });
});
```

Details on the api: [pm2-api](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-api/)